# Is "Homo sum, Deus ero" a correct way to say this?

Tags: syntax, conjugation, english-to-latin-translation

I'm coming up with a title for a song, and I thought "I'm a human, I will be a god" or "I'm human, I will be God" was pretty sweet sounding, but translating it into a short Latin saying would make it even better. Since I remember the word order "*homo sum*" from the famous humanist motto, I wonder if adding "*Deus ero*" after a simple comma would be correct? I came to this quite simply via analogy, since "*ero*" is the first person future form of "to be".

Answer (score 9):

That works fine. The Romans might have done it in a different order:

> Homo sum, ero deus.

You could also say

> Homo sum, deus futurus.

This would be roughly "I am a man [who] is to be a god."

Yet another way to do this would be

> Homo sum, fiam deus.

Which means "I am a man, I will become a god."

By the way, there's a great story about the emperor Vespasian told by the historian Suetonius. After Julius Caesar died, Roman emperors were considered, to a greater or lesser degree, to become divine when they died, at which point people worshipped them as gods. Vespasian's last words, according to Suetonius, were, "Væ, puto deus fio," which means, "Alas, I think I am becoming a god."

Comment: I'd say that *ero deus* means "I will be god" and *fiam deus* "I will become god". Choosing between these two is choosing emphasis between the process and the resulting state.

Comment: Yes. I intended my answer to make that distinction clear but I see that it did a half-assed job of doing so. I've edited so it does a full-assed job.

Comment: Now that you put it that way, I wonder if an *autem* fits there, like *Homo sum, ero autem deus* (or *deus autem ero*). I'd also add that an important proportion of Latin speakers (i.e., most of them since the IV century AD) would have been horrified by the idea of a man claiming to be able to become God.

Comment: @Rafael: Barbarians!

Comment: I think that rhetorically *autem* is overkill. (Also *verum* would probably be a better way to say "but" in this circumstance—autem is usually used to change the subject or to resume an interrupted narrative.)